# Rename network folder with spaces in it

Tags: batch-file, file-rename, unc

I have a folder on a remote server named ***Backup Job [Hostname].[Date]*** which is located in ***\\XXX\backup\Hostname*** that I want to rename into simply ***Backup***. Since ***[Hostname]*** and ***[Date]*** are added later on I don't know the exact filename in advance.

When I try to rename the folder from a remote computer with the following line

```
for /D %f in (\\XXX\backup\Hostame\Backup*) do rename %f Backup
```

it gets translated into

```
rename \\XXX\backup\Hostame\Backup Job Hostname.Date Backup
```

and throws a

```
Syntax incorrect
```

I am pretty sure this is due to the spaces in the folder name, but how do I get past this?

Comment: Use quotation marks as always?

Comment: `for /D %%f in (\\XXX\backup\Hostame\Backup*) do rename "%%f" Backup`

Comment: If it is just a single folder why are you using `FOR /D`?

Comment: `for /D %%F in ("\\XXX\backup\Hostame\Backup*") do ren "%%~F" "Backup"`, or even `ren "\\XXX\backup\Hostame\Backup Job Hostname.Date" "Backup"`, if you know the exact name in advance, that's it!

Comment: @Squashman I don't know the name of the folder in advance

Comment: @ThomasWeller That was just incredibly stupid of me.. Some workdays are just to long. THANKS a LOT! :)

Comment: `move "\\Server\share\folder\Backup*" "\\server\share\folder\backup"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Skript was missing the needed quotation marks as explained in the comments of the question. The line should have been:

```
for /D %f in (\\XXX\backup\Hostame\Backup*) do rename "%f" Backup
```